# Why copying the same text in 2 different textboxes does not always equal to true?

Tags: winforms, textbox

On my winform I have 3 textboxes, lets say that after I click a button, textbox1 shows "Hello" Then a copy & paste the word "World" into textbox3 and based on a condition if textbox3 == to textbox1 then textbox2 you show "World".Sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. Why?

```
if(textBox1.Text == textBox3.Text)               
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Load(cmd2.ExecuteReader());
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    textBox2.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
}
```

Comment: "Hello" doesn't equal "World"?  I think you need to edit your question to make it more clear.

Comment: Maybe you need to make sure there are no extraneous spaces, such as:
if (textBox1.Text.Trim().Equals(textBox3.Text.Trim()). . .

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the equal check, you need to debug the values

Comment: @Draco18s sorry I meant to say that textbox1 and textbox3 show "Hello" and if true textbox2 shows "World". I have to say also that I am copying a pasting a whole paragrah in French, the reason being is if textbox1 == textbox3 than textbox2 shows the English translation from the database.

Comment: The problem is likely that the language you are working in (unclear) treats strings as immutable.  That means that `var1 = "Hello"; var2 = "Hello"` involves two instances of type String which are not the same object (that is, pointers to data, the data just happens to be the same, but the *pointers* are not the same).  In which case, you should do `textBox1.Text.equals(textBox3.Text)`

Comment: Both `.Text` properties should be able to be compared without a problem. You mentioned French, is it possible that it is related to a localization issue? Can you specify the CultureInfo `if(string.Compare(textBox1.Text.Trim(), textBox2.Text.Trim(), false, new CultureInfo("fr-FR")) == 0) { /*...*/ };` or try using `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` instead.